Как в React Native при нажатии на Pressible изменить цвет и текста и иконки одновременно?
При нажатии на элемент Pressible должен меняться и цвет текста и цвет иконки, но я не знаю, как это сделать, потому что внутри можно передать только один pressed и один возврат внутри. Блок с иконкой оставил для полноты картины — если его расскоментировать и поставить после Text, текст пропадет.
return (
    ‹ View styLe=(infoLinksStyles.wrapper}>
    {dataInfoLinks.map ((item =>
    ‹ Pressable style=({pressed})=> [
    infoLinksstyles.blocks,
    pressed && {backgroundColor: Color.active, borderRadius:16, padding:5}]} key=(item.id}> {/* ‹FontAwesome name={item.icon) size={item.size) color={item.color}/> */} 
    {((pressed}) =>(
    return (
    ‹Text style={[infoLinksStyles.headStyle, pressed && {color: '#fff'},]}>(item.head)</Text>
    </Pressable>
    </View>```


